# api json data processing for using d3js tree

Tags: d3.js

I get data from etherscan api.
(https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs&fromBlock=379224&toBlock=latest&address=0xFa85069E3D1Ca1B09945CF11d2365386b1E4430A&topic0=0x16e746f9be6c4b545700b04df27afb9fceabf59b94ef1c816e78a435059fabea&apikey=XR15QV2PDRBYRAW82234MQ33RH7PFVWGJZ)

I want to make a d3js tree after data processing
Of incoming data
The first value is the children's address, and the second value is the parent's address.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEFUi.png)

I want to list this data all the way to the child's child until there are no children.

using d3js tree
I plan to make it.

This is what I want to make.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLpqr.jpg)